# Checking proxy anonymity

Tags: c#

I am building a small C# app to check how anonymous a proxy is.

What "tests" should I perform in order to determine that a proxy is absolutely anonymous?

Is the following reliable?

```
http://www.iprivacytools.com/proxy-checker-anonymity-test/
```

If it is I could build a `httpwebrequest` using a given proxy to parse results

Comment: You're gonna need to be more specific in defining what you consider to be anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous proxy does not expose your IP in HTTP headers. So yes, this test can give a hint.